# import issue using exec(compile()) in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, import, nameerror

Windows 10, Python 3.5.1 x64 here.

This is weird... Let's say I have this script, called `do.py`. Please note the `import string` statement:

```
import string

# Please note that if the print statement is OUTSIDE 'main()', it works.
# It's like if 'main()' can't see the imported symbols from 'string'
def main():
    print(string.ascii_lowercase)

main()
```

I want to run it from a "launcher script", in a subthread, like this (`launcher.py`):

```
import sys
import threading

sys.argv.append('do.py')

def run(script, filename):
    exec(compile(script, filename, 'exec'))

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as _:
    script = _.read()

# But this WORKS:
# exec(compile(script, sys.argv[1], 'exec'))

thread = threading.Thread(name='Runner', target=run, args=(script, sys.argv[1]))
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

It dies with the following error:

```
Exception in thread Runner:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "tmpgui.py", line 7, in run
    exec(compile(script, filename, 'exec'))
  File "do.py", line 6, in <module>
    main()
  File "do.py", line 4, in main
    print(string.ascii_lowercase)
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

That is, the exec'ed code is not importing `string` properly or something like that, and within `main()` the `string` module is not visible.

This is not the full code of my project, which is too big to post here, but the bare minimum I've created which mimics the problem.

Just in case someone is curious, I'm rewriting an old program of mine which imported the `main()` function of a script and ran that function with the standard output streams redirected to a `tkinter` text box. Instead of importing a function from the script, I want to load the script and run it. I don't want to use `subprocess` for a whole variety of reasons, I prefer to run the "redirected" code in a thread and communicate with the main thread which is the one handling the GUI. And that part works perfectly, the only problem I have is this and I can't understand why is happening!

My best bet: I should be passing something in globals or locals dictionaries to `exec`, but I'm at a lost here...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can this be the problem?: if I don't pass any global or local dictionary to the `exec` call, that call is run in the scope of the `main()` function in the launcher, and the `import string` imports the module only in `locals()`? But then, the `main()` function in `do.py` should still be able to access that symbol, because it is defined in a 'higher' scope, am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec(thing)` is equivalent to `exec(thing, globals(), locals())`.

Thus,

- the local symbol table of *do.py* is the local symbol table of the `run` function
- the global symbol table of *do.py* is the global symbol table of *launcher.py*

`import string` imports the module and binds it to the variable in the local space, which is the local space of the `run` function. You can verify this:

```
def run(script, filename):
    try:
        exec(compile(script, filename, 'exec'))
    finally:
        assert 'string' in locals(), "won't fail because 'import' worked properly"
```

`main` has a separate local scope, but it shares the global symbol table with *do.py* and, consequently, with *launcher.py*.

Python tried to find the variable named `string` inside both local (it's empty) and global symbol tables of `main`, but failed, and raised the `NameError`.

Pass one empty dictionary in a call to `exec`:

```
def run(script, filename):
    exec(compile(script, filename, 'exec'), {})
```

Comment: Thanks, vaultah, this fixed my problem. As you can see from my _self comment_, I suspected this may be the reason, but I didn't know the solution was to pass an empty dictionary which `code` could use. Thanks A LOT!

Comment: @RaúlNúñezdeArenasCoronado: no problem :) If you pass in one (possibly empty) dictionary, [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) will use it as *globals* and *locals*. From the docs: *"If only globals is provided, it must be a dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local variables. ... Remember that at module level, globals and locals are the same dictionary."* Technically, you can give exec any dictionary.